# symfony, "Missing value for primary key usn on GameBackend\Entity\CrossFire\Fame"

Tags: php, symfony

I am frustrated.. I have added the JoinColumn for both values, yet it outputs

> Missing value for primary key famepoint on GameBackend\Entity\CrossFire\Fame

Character.php

```
/**
 * @var Fame
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Fame")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="LEV", referencedColumnName="FAME_GRADE")
 */
private $level = 0;


/**
 * @return Fame
 */
public function getLevel()
{
    return $this->level;
}

/**
 * @param Fame $level
 * @return self
 */
public function setLevel($level)
{
    $this->level = $level;
    return $this;
}
```

Fame.php

```
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="USN", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $usn;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="FAME_POINT", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $famepoint = 0;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="FAME_GRADE", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $famelevel = 0;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->usn;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $usn
     * @return self
     */
    public function setId($usn)
    {
        $this->usn = $usn;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getfamepoint()
    {
        return $this->famepoint;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $famepoint
     * @return self
     */
    public function setfamepoint($famepoint)
    {
        $this->famepoint = $famepoint;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getfamelevel()
    {
        return $this->famelevel;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $famelevel
     * @return self
     */
    public function setfamelevel($famelevel)
    {
        $this->famelevel = $famelevel;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Notice: I am relatively new to this and I have absolutely no clue what may cause the issue, I have read through multiple topics and nothing helped me so far.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

**referencedColumnName** inside your annotation should be Name of the primary key identifier that is used for joining of this relation as stated in http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html And your $famelevel actually isn't. I belive that you should refer to $usn field in your association as it is actual primary key of your Fame entity that you joining. Hope that will help!

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but I actually want to bind famelevel and Level, if I try to do it via USN it does show me the list but buggy, could you help me how to bind FameLevel and Level?